# Blazor webassembly ASP.NET Core hosted. How to redirect to page passing data?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, hosted

I've created a Blazor webassembly ASP.NET Core hosted solution. The solution has three projects: `BlazorApp1.Client`, `BlazorApp1.Server` and `BlazorApp1.Shared`.

In `BlazorApp1.Server` part, I have a controller with a `HttpPost` method called `MyPost` that receives some data.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Register")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public ActionResult MyPost([FromForm] string data)
    {
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

I have to redirect to a page called `Index` that is in `BlazorApp1.Client` (at `http://localhost:48518/Index`), passing the data that I've received in the method `MyPost`.

The problem is how redirect to index passing the data?

How to redirect from `MyPost` method (in `BlazorApp.Server`) to an `Index` page in the `BlazorApp.Client`?

I look forward to your responses, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route to pass value to razor component.
Change the Index.razor like

```
@page "/index/{data?}"

<p>@data</p>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string? data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can pass value by call the URL `http://localhost:45818/index/mystring`
[image]

You can use following code to redirect in a back-end method.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Register")]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public ActionResult MyPost([FromForm] string data)
        {
            return Redirect("http://localhost:45818/index/mystring");
        }
```

If you redirect from a razor page. inject and use navigationmanager.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<button @onclick=test>Redirect</button>

@code{
    public void test()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is the code for the Post method (asp.net core) to route to the index of the webassembly project on the client side. All the code i ran got me an error. How would you write the code to route to the index in the MyPost method?

Comment: Did you go this "mypost" url directly?  or using httpclient to call this method like call an api?

Comment: mypost is called from an external page. Example: A user has to login  in a external web page (single sign on) then the login web SSO return a url callback with a token. i got the token in the method myPost. So now i have to redirect the token to another page in my app located in the Client project (BlazorApp1.Client)

Comment: @user21980057 Anyway, if you need redirect from back-end method, use `return redirect()`. If you redirect from a front-end razor page, use `NavigationManager`. I have modify the answer you can have a look.